# Dim the page and show a loading indicator

Tags: css

I would like to dim the page and show a loading indicator. I got the jQuery set. It's the CSS that I can't get to work. It's the diming the background that I can't do. Any ideas?

This is what I got (shows the indicator in the center of the page):

```
#Loading
{
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1000;
    height: 31px;
    width: 60px;
    left: 50%;
    top: 35%;
    background-image: url('../Images/ajax-loader-bright.gif');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Since you've tagged your question as CSS 3:

```
background: rgba(0,0,0,.5) url('../Images/ajax-loader-bright.gif') no-repeat;
width:100%;
height:100%;
position:fixed;
top:0;
left:0;
z-index:999;
```

You can adjust the dimming level by changing alpha (`.5`) in the line containing `rgba`.

Comment: this does not place the loader in the middle tho, its in my left corner

Comment: to place it in the middle just add `50% 50%` at the end of background declaration.

Answer (score 5):

to create dim page using jquery with/without image can also be done with this plugin
http://jquery.malsup.com/block/#demos

to generate ajax loading page there is http://www.ajaxload.info/ which is awesome.

Answer (score 4):

You could use a separate div positioned absolutely with width and height set to 100%.  Then set the background of this div to #000 (black) and its opacity to 50% (or whatever level of dimness you want).

```
<div id='dim_wrapper' style='width:100%; height:100%; background:#000; z-index:10'>&nbsp;</div>
<script>
$("#dim_wrapper").animate({
    'opacity':0.5
});
</script>
```

Comment: Plus a z-index greater than 0.

Comment: should this wrapp the other or?

Comment: No these should be separate unless you want the opacity to also be applied to the indicator.

Comment: I had to add `opacity: 0` and `position: fixed` to the style.  
You can also use the `fadeTo()` function to animate the opacity.